# Iterating through a comma separated list in Matlab gives the error: "FOR expression comma separated list must have exactly one item."

Tags: arrays, regex, excel, matlab

I'm trying to clean up some text data by getting rid of unnecessary junk in some of the text. The text currently exists in an Excel dataset, all in one column, with each "item" of text occupying one row each. These items are all character strings with a few to many words in each. I extracted the items using the code below (2nd block) and it gave me list1, which is a 14510x1 cell.

I'm trying to run this for loop in Matlab:

```
function list2 = cleanup(exp_spec,list1)
for i = list1{(1:length(list1))};
        str = i;
        replace = '';
        list2{i} = regexprep(str,exp_spec,replace);
    end
end
```

I got "list1" from the excel sheet like this:

```
[~,txt,~] = xlsread('spreadsheet.xlsx','T:T');
    list1 = txt;
```

When I try to run the code with this line,

```
list2 = cleanup('&#[0-9]+;',list1);
clean_list = list2;
```

it throws the error:

```
FOR expression comma separated list must have exactly one
item.

    Error in cleanup (line 2)
    for i = list1{(1:length(list1))};

    Error in project_main (line 57)
        list2 = cleanup('&#[0-9]+;',list1);
```

I've been searching for HOURS trying to figure out a solution and so far I've found nothing. I tried transposing list1 and it still didn't work. Also, when I call something like list1{1} etc., it always works correctly and returns the entire string. I'm pretty new to Matlab so the answer might be very simple! If I left something helpful out please let me know. I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Given a cell c, the output of `c{1:2}` produces a comma-separated list equivalent to `c{1},c{2}`. If you substitute that explicit comma separated list into

```
for i=c{1:2}
```

you get

```
for i=c{1},c{2}
```

which isn't legal syntax, so you get an error.

I think it would be more straightforward to iterate through the indices themselves, something like this:

```
function list2 = cleanup(exp_spec,list1)
    replace = '';
    for i = 1:length(list1)
        list2{i} = regexprep(list1{i},exp_spec,replace);
    end
end
```

An advanced way to do this is with cellfun and an anonymous function:

```
l2 = cellfun(@(str)regexprep(str,exp_spec,replace), ...
     l1, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Of course it would be so simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please note I just removed an unneeded copy from my sample code, it doesn't do anything but slow down the code :-)